# How to import .bobj files in Blender?

Tags: import, fluid-simulation

I received a set of *.bobj files. Those files were not created with Blender, they were generated by an external fluid simulator. I am not familiar with the physics engine of blender and I don't need it. I only need to read the mesh for rendering purposes. Using Blender 2.68a.

How to import those files in Blender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Bobj file sounds like it could be a Binary OBJ file, However i believe this is not a specific standard of file.

Blender's Fluid simulator outputs bobj.gz as a format in binary, and compressed.

Edited:

bobj files are used in the fluid tab of the physics settings.

Make sure the bobj.gz files are in a directory of their own, and then goto that directory in the highlighted field.
Make sure you only have the directory name in the field, and not the file name of the fluid cache.

You also need to make sure the file names do not change from **fluidsurface_final_xxxx.bobj** 
and set the viewport Display to Final.

[image]

Comment: Actually it is a .bobj.gz  (Binary OBJ), I decompressed it because I thought it was compressed only for e-mail sending purposes, didn't know it was actually part of the file logic. If that is the file, any idea how to import it?

Comment: i have edited my original answer

Comment: Would appreciate if you could resize this screenshot, it is unnecessarily big.

Comment: That made the trick...thank you very much.